# Ограничение по времени

Tags: mysqli, php, html, mysql

Как вычислить время, а точнее как определить сколько записей в бд за день находиться по определенному полю, к примеру Дима отправил Игорю 20 личных сообщений на сайте, если он хочет отправить ещё столько или более то этого сделать нельзя то есть ограничение за день по 20 сообщений, как мне составить выборку в базу данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE user_id = <ид юзера> AND DATE(datetime) = DATE(NOW())
```

Получить количество сообщений которые отправил пользователь user_id за сегодня